# Toolbar buttons not visible for new usergroup in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I created a new usergroup (Partners) and a new viewing access level (Partners) in joomla.

The idea is that that usergroup has access to only a single component and only specific modules (all of this in the administrator interface).

This all works fine except for the fact that the user cannot create nor edit anything in any component. `Create` is set to `Allowed`, yet no toolbar buttons are visible. I tried setting everything to `Allowed` in the component. I tried different components to no avail.

The `Partners` usergroup is the sole group with viewing access `Partners`.

NOTE:
I would also like to note that the component name is **NOT** visible in the toolbar area

Settings for component:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXWKh.png

viewing access level:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPsIj.png

Comment: What did you assign the group parent to when creating the usergroup? Did you also set `Allow administrator access` to `Allowed` in the component permissions?

Comment: @Lodder `Partners` is a child group of `Registered` but all the settings are overriden.

Comment: Did you also set `Allow administrator access` to `Allowed` in the component permissions? Also, can you provide a screenshot of the settings for the component, and viewing access level?

Comment: @Lodder yes those are set. I added pictures. I moved the usergroup out to be under public which doesn't work at all

Comment: The toolbar and title module in the admin modules list were set to Special. I set them to public which let them appear!